# Ayuda con Servicio rest Angular 4 Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, angular, django, djangorestframework

estoy realizando una aplicación empleando `Django` y `Angular 4` sin embargo cuando trato de consumir el servicio brindado por `django` me da el siguiente error.

> *Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed
>   access.*

El servicio me esta funcionado perfectamente sin embargo, ya que llegan los datos al navegador si embargo Angular 4 no sabe como entender los datos

El código que tengo en *Angular 4* es el siguiente:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, RequestOptions, Response} from '@angular/http';


import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
// import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

import * as moment from 'moment';
import {Reserva} from "./reserva";
import {RESERVAS} from "./reserva.mock";

@Injectable()
export class ReservaService {

   private reservaUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/reservas/';  // URL to web api
   constructor(private http: Http) { }




  getReservas(): Observable<Reserva[]>{

    /**
     * Servicio consumiendo los datos REST
     */

    // let headers = new Headers();
    // headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    // // headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET');
    // // headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 'Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');
    // headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','http://127.0.0.1:8000');
    // // headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    // headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    // headers.append("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded, application/json");
    // let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers});
    // return this.http.get(this.reservaUrl)
    //   .toPromise()
    //   .then(response => response.json().data as Reserva[])
    //   .catch(this.handleError)

      let cpHeaders = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
      let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: cpHeaders });

    return this.http.get(this.reservaUrl, options)
                    .map(this.extractData)
                    .catch(this.handleError);


  }

  private extractData(res: Response) {
     console.info("Los datos", res.json())
     let body = res.json();
     return body.data || { };
  }

  private handleError (error: Response | any) {
    // In a real world app, you might use a remote logging infrastructure
    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof Response) {
      const body = error.json() || '';
      const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
      errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
      errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }
    console.error(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }




}
```

He realizado diferentes con la clase `Headers`, pero ninguna me funciona.

Por favor si alguien tiene resulto este problema y me puede ayudar será de gran ayuda.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola Duany, te saludo y te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, saludos!

Comment: Buenas. ¿Podrias incluir el componente desde el cual estás invocando ReservaService?

Comment: Amigo, eso sucede cuando sirves aplicaciones desde distintos dominios, para eso debes entender como funciona [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) que es una restricción que existe, en la cual debes autorizar desde tu servidor el acceso de peticines provenientes de otro dominio, para eso es importante el uso del header `Origin`, Django-rest-framework te ofrece un [plugin](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/ajax-csrf-cors/#cors),  para manejar eso, en ese apartado te explican que debes hacer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muchas gracias cjara, por tu respuesta y tenias todo la razón yo estaba empleando ese plugins pero me faltaba poner en el settings en la variable MIDDLEWARE las siguientes clases:

```
'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
'corsheaders.middleware.CorsPostCsrfMiddleware'
```

Por lo que el código que pusé era correcto. Muchas gracias nuevamente. Sldos